# zabbix - trigger alerts from web scenario

Tags: zabbix

I have created a trigger for a check on a web scenario (using the example below). It triggers an alert if there are 3 values equal 0 within 60secs.

My understanding was that web.test.fail returns the step number when it fails.

What I do not understand is how the following example would trigger an alert - if there is only 1 step in web scenario for test.example.com, and it fails, wouldn't web.test.fail would return 1 instead of 0? Wouldn't that mean there would be 3 values equal 1 within 60 secs? In this case, how would the following example work? Am I understanding this wrong?

Trigger example:

```
{hosts1:web.test.fail[test.example.com].count(60,0)}=3
```

Answer (score 2):

The trigger expression {hosts1:web.test.fail[test.example.com].last()} will return a result of the latest test:

- **0** - OK. The web scenario **test.example.com** (all steps) was tested successfully;
- **1** - The first step of the web scenario **test.example.com** was failed (you have only one step of the scenario as you told);
- **UNKNOWN** - The web host is unreachable.

If the trigger expression will return **UNKNOWN** state or value more than 0, the trigger will generate **PROBLEM** alert.

If you want to generate alert after three consecutive failed checks then rewrite the trigger expression as:

```
{hosts1:web.test.fail[test.example.com].sum(#3)}>0
```

This trigger will work with any step counts of your web scenario. It sends **PROBLEM** alert at first failed test and sends **OK** restore alert after three consecutive successful checks (180 secs after service was fully restored).

Comment: Trigger should not become unknown if the webhost/service is down - web scenario should properly detect that was a failure. Regarding the expression, this is simpler: `{hosts1:web.test.fail[test.example.com].min(#3)=1}`.

Comment: Wont' the following trigger alerts repeatedly when the last 3 values are 1 ? 
`{hosts1:web.test.fail[test.example.com].min(#3)=1}`

Comment: @Dextor What Zabbix version do you use?

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy Zabbix 3.4

Comment: @Dextor, no, unless you enable multiple problem trigger generation (which you should not).

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy thank you for the update, but it still suggests that trigger could go in the unknown state - I'm not aware of a case when that could happen. Do you have an example?

Comment: @Richlv What if in my web scenario Update Interval was set to 30sec and attempts is set to 3? Should I set it to min(#1) if I want it to trigger within 90 secs ? Does web.test.fail take into account the number of attempts which was set? 

`{hosts1:web.test.fail[test.example.com].min(#3)=1}`

Comment: Attempts are done every interval time. That is, your scenario would be executed every 30 seconds and if it would fail, it would try 2 more times. These attempts do not count towards values. `min(#1)` would take the minimum of a single last value - it would be the same was `last()`.

Comment: @Dextor @Richlv I'm sorry. I wasn't right. I've tested all on Zabbix 3.2 and updated my answer. @Richlv I think `sum(#3)>0` will be better than `min(#3)=1`. It will work with any step counts of a web scenario and will send the `OK` alert after 3 consecutive successful checks.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy, I'd go with `max(#3)=0` in that case - works with any number of steps, recovers upon 3 successful checks. `sum()` seems a bit more confusing here.

Comment: @Richiv Well. It's a good solution too.